# С# изменить атрибуты файла

Tags: c#

Как средствами С# изменить атрибут файла сохранив значение остальных его атрибутов?

```
File.SetAttributes(file_path, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Так у файла установится атрибут ReadOnly а все остальные пропадут.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Вот так:

```
File.SetAttributes(file_path, File.GetAttributes(file_path) | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Или так:

```
new FileInfo(file_path).Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает.

Comment: @Roman если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его стрелкой вверх. Если решил ваш вопрос, то поставьте зеленую галку. Нет нужды благодарить комментариями.